# How to ignore SSL certificate validation in .Net-Core 2 on CentOS

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, centos, httpclient

I'm building a console application using **.NetCore 2.0**

This application is making a REST call for a server which running on **"https" but his certificate is not valid.** To support this issue I override the "**ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback**" function:

```
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler;

        if (IgnoreSslErrors)
        {
            httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    Log.Warn($"Invalid SSL/TLS server certificate: {errors}");
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        }
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true);
```

This .net Core application work great on Windows 10. But when I'm running it on CentOS 7 (1511 version) I'm getting this error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The handler does not support custom handling of certificates with this combination of libcurl (7.29.0) and its SSL backend ("NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC").
>      at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.SslProvider.SetSslOptionsForUnsupportedBackend(EasyRequest easy, ClientCertificateProvider certProvider)
>      at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.SslProvider.SetSslOptions(EasyRequest easy, ClientCertificateOption clientCertOption)
>      at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.EasyRequest.InitializeCurl()
>      at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.ActivateNewRequest(EasyRequest easy) 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Is is a bug in .NetCore?

Should I update some libraries in CentOS? Can I use alternative code that will work in CentOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in CentOS by downloading a newer version of "**libcurl-openssl**"

```
'yum install libcurl-openssl-7.43.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm'
```

and then redirect powershell to discover the new dynamic library.

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/shibboleth/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

*If you run the app as a service,
Make sure to add this to the ".service" file under the "[Service]" section:

```
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/shibboleth/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

More detailed information can be found in these posts:

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-1296
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2511